# Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps a little different

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I want to create a store locator with Google Maps.

I have a database with a table of TOURISTIC OBJECTS (with their coordinates) and a table of HOTELS (also with their coordinates).

I want the user to have the possibility, after he loads the page of the Tower of London, let's say, to see what hotels are near the object within a 10-kilometer radius and display the results on Google Maps with markers.

So far, I've only managed to fetch the hotels in a 10-kilometer range from the database with the haversin formula and display them as text:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  nume,  poze, descriere, link, (
(
    ACOS( SIN( 45.515038 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( latitudine * PI( ) /180 ) +
          COS( 45.515038 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( latitudine * PI( ) /180 ) *
          COS( ( 25.366935 - longitudine ) * PI( ) /180 )
    ) *180 / PI( )
) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
) AS distance
FROM `unitati`
HAVING distance <= '10'
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30");
```

How can I display them as markers on the map?

I found this and I thought it could help me: http://code.google.com/intl/ro-RO/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html, but it has a different logic: the user types in the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example takes your query (and you'll need to edit the 45.515038 and 25.366935 with the lat/lng for each objective) and outputs it as a JS array of arrays (you could make it more formal JSON if you like)

It then loops through that array, making markers for each and placing them on a map. Finally, it adds a click listener to each so that it'll display relevant information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
#map_canvas{width:500px;height:500px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
<?php
//you'll first need to connect to your db
//you also have to edit the lat/lng in your SELECT statement to be that of your objective
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  latitudine, longitudine, nume,  poze, descriere, link, (
(
    ACOS( SIN( 45.515038 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( latitudine * PI( ) /180 ) +
          COS( 45.515038 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( latitudine * PI( ) /180 ) *
          COS( ( 25.366935 - longitudine ) * PI( ) /180 )
    ) *180 / PI( )
) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
) AS distance
FROM `unitati`
HAVING distance <= '10'
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30");
$c=0;
echo "var data=[";
while($markers=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($c>0){echo ",";}
    echo "['".$markers[0]."','".$markers[1]."','".$markers[2]."','".$markers[3]."','".$markers[4]."','".$markers[5]."','".$markers[6]."'"."]";
    $c++;
}
echo "];";
?>
    //var data=[['45','-73','home','poz1','desc1','link1'],['43','-75','work','poz2','desc2','link2']];
    var places=new Array();
    var map;
    var MyInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Loading...'});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var point=new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0],data[i][1]);
        var a = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,map: map, icon:'someHotelIcon.png'});
        a.lat=data[i][0];
        a.lng=data[i][1];
        a.nume=data[i][2];
        a.poze=data[i][3];
        a.desc=data[i][4];
        a.url=data[i][5];
        places.push(a);
    }
    for(i=0;i<places.length;i++){
        var point2=new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat,places[i].lng);
        bounds.extend(point2);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var objLoc=new google.maps.LatLng(45.515038,26.366935);
    var objectiveMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: objLoc,map: map, icon:'objectiveIcon.png'});    //---------------Marker for objective
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        var marker = places[i];
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        MyInfoWindow.setContent(this.nume+'<br/>'+this.desc+'<br/><a href=\"'+this.url+'\">link</a>');
        MyInfoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: each objective has it`s own php page, but i dont have "function search locationsnear " like u say. i only have a query , the one i wrote in the question which tells the database to retrieve only the hotels that are located in 10 kilometers range. be more specific please

Comment: Just replace the lat/LNG (45.5 and 25.3) in your query on each page with the objective coordinates

Comment: Here is a sample page to get you started

Comment: Your example is super cool ! Thank you ! I was able to show on the map the hotels, but, because there is always a but, if i uncomment that var line, it only shows that point, it doesnt show the results of the search. Odd..

Comment: It's because that line overwrites the search results, it needs to be either/or, glad it helped

Comment: it shouldn`t be AND ? because i want that point and the search results? not to be to "greedy" but can i add a different marker for the objectiv point? so that i doesnt confuse the users?

Comment: and how exactly do i position the either? or? and ?

Comment: I'll make some edits in a few hours...there's an icon attribute you can set for the marker

Comment: Thank you. i ll wait for your modifications !

Comment: so, I added the icon parameter, you'll need to replace `someHotelIcon.png` and `objectiveIcon.png` with your own icons. And now there is another spot to edit the hardcoded lat/lng

Comment: It s absoulutly wonderful ! Thank you ! offtopic: you should visit 45.515038 25.36693 :)

Comment: i kept my old results which only displayed text and picture from the database and i added your cool map displaying hotels.  let`s say the search retrieved 3 hotels in the range of 10 km of an objective . i display the 3 hotels, by text, photo for each and a little description. i want to add a "display on the map" link to each hotel so that the user cand really locate the specific hotel. i added your map displaying module but i want when a user push "display on map" of hotel A , the google map appear and it is centered on the marker of the specific hotel .

Comment: Ask that as another question (search first though, that's not uncommon)...people don't read comments as much so it'll be more helpful to others that way

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do distance/geolocation based search use MySQL's geo-spatial stuff. It is far more efficient then straight haversine formula.

These are just some snippets but they should help put you on the path to awesomeness:

First off you table will need a geospatial column to hold your lat/lon, mine is called coordinate and is on type `point`:

```
`coordinate` point NOT NULL,
```

next you will need to add a geospatial index:

```
SPATIAL KEY `coordinate` (`coordinate`)
```

(Both of these are part of my table create sql syntax).

This bit will help insert your lat/lon data into the coordinate column:

```
$data['coordinate'] = ("GeomFromText( 'POINT({$data['longitude']} {$data['latitude']})')");
```

This little bit will would replace your distance calc (as part of a larger SQL query):

```
$sql = str_replace(
            array('%LATITUDE%','%LONGITUDE%'), 
            array($latitude, $longitude),
            '(GLength( LineString( coordinate ,Point(%LONGITUDE%, %LATITUDE%)))) AS distance'
        );
```

The above query s good for euclidean geometry (i.e. the world is flat), but the world isn't so you should use the below to help narrow down your results list. For real accuracy and correct ordering use the haversine or better formula on the results that are brought back from these 2 SQL queries.

This bit will act as a bounding rectangle/box (anythng not inside the box will not be returned - use it to replace `HAVING distance <= '10'`, you'll find the query faster - especially with lots of data). My calculations for max/min lat/lon are just examples, you can do better :-) :

```
        $minLat = $latitude - 0.5;
        $maxLat = $latitude + 0.5;
        $minLon = $longitude - 0.5;
        $maxLon = $longitude + 0.5;

        $sql = str_replace(
            array('%MINLAT%', '%MAXLAT%','%MINLON%', '%MAXLON%'), 
            array($minLat, $maxLat, $minLon, $maxLon),
            "MBRCONTAINS(GeomFromText('POLYGON((%MINLON% %MAXLAT%,%MAXLON% %MAXLAT%,%MAXLON% %MINLAT%,%MINLON% %MINLAT%, %MINLON% %MAXLAT%))'), `coordinate`)"
        );
```

Comment: i found the haversin formula to be a much easier way , considering the fact that i`m new to all of this . i will not have many hotels at the start, logically, so for the moment i think i will remain to the haversin formula .I was interested in the visual display of the hotels on a google map,how can i do that. i suspect it can be done with the store locator but i need some hints

Comment: Alot depends on hardware but I found plain haversine was ok for a few thousand rows, but above that performance does fall. If you think you are going to get anywhere near 50,000+ then definitely look at GeoSpatial. (Don't worry, you can implement it later without too much pain) I've never really tried displaying stuff on google maps so i'll have to let someone else help you on that

Comment: i wish i would have 50 000 hotels in my database :) for the start i will be pleased with a few houndreds :)

Comment: Then you avoid using geospatial queries to start with unless you have the time to implement them. Once you find your queries are too slow then you can refactor your code

Comment: (also if you have found this question to be useful an upvote would be nice :-)

Comment: your answers are very usefull but i dont have the requiered reputation to upvote:( 10x !